# Programmatically trigger onRowClicked-event

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Is there a way to manually trigger the Grid-Event **onRowClicked** programmatically? If I set a node to selected via

```
node.setSelected(true);
```

, the event isn't being triggered... Only if I really click on it, but I need to trigger it programmatically too, as a reaction to a service-call.

Comment: do you have knowledge of rowid or row-index value with you?

Comment: @sandeepjoshi No, but another attribute. I'm already identifiying the correct row and setting it to selected as written above. But this does not trigger the onRowClicked-Event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems pretty simple to me. Just call the `onRowClicked` function on your `gridOptions`. Seeing as you already have your node, you should be able to get the row and pass it to your `onRowClicked` function.

```
var gridOptions = { 
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: rowData,
  onRowClicked: function(params)
  {
    console.log('Row Make: ' + params.data.make);
  }
};

function clickRowOne()
{
  const node = gridOptions.api.getRowNode(0);
  gridOptions.onRowClicked(node);
}
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/DBwEBk7PVgwM6P1p).